Unity 3d snap point increase or decrease the dimension casually during attachment or detachment object
when I try to mount one object on another via snap points the object randomly becomes larger or smaller.
In the code I will show I recall the prefab of the engine that must be assembled and I also recall another script "PartToBeAssembled" which takes care of adding and removing the kinematic from the object.
this also happens when I try to detach the two objects.
public class AttachementPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region Events
    public delegate void AttachmentCompleted(GameObject attachmentPoint, GameObject assembledObject);
    public static event AttachmentCompleted hasBeenCompleted;
    public delegate void SeparationCompleted(GameObject attachmentPoint, GameObject separatedObject);
    public static event SeparationCompleted hasBeenSeparated;
    #endregion
    //#region PhotonEvents
    //private const byte OBJECT_ASSEMBLED_EVENT = 1;
    //private const byte OBJECT_DISASSEMBLED_EVENT = 2;
    //#endregion

    [SerializeField]
    public List<GameObject> m_CompatibleObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    [SerializeField]
    private bool m_attach = false;
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 m_PositionOffset;
    [SerializeField]
    private Vector3 m_RotationOffset;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool notAttachedYet = true;
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject installationPoint;
    [SerializeField]
    private List<GameObject> snappingPoints;
    [SerializeField]
    private List<GameObject> containers;
    [SerializeField]
    private Material m_DefaultMaterial;
    [SerializeField]
    private Material m_VisibleMaterial;
    private GameObject m_AssembledObject;
    RaiseEventOptions options = new RaiseEventOptions { Receivers = ReceiverGroup.All };

    private void Start()
    {
        m_DefaultMaterial = gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material;
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.NetworkingClient.EventReceived += NetworkingClient_EventReceived;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.NetworkingClient.EventReceived -= NetworkingClient_EventReceived;
    }
    private void NetworkingClient_EventReceived(EventData obj)
    {
        if (obj.Code == PhotonEvents.OBJECT_ASSEMBLED_EVENT)
        {
            object[] evData = (object[])obj.CustomData;
            GameObject attachmentPoint = FindCorrectAttachmentPoint((int)evData[0]);
            GameObject objectToAssemble = FindCorrectPart((int)evData[1]);
            if (attachmentPoint == gameObject && objectToAssemble.GetComponent<PartToBeAssembled>().isAssembled == false)
            {
                AssembleToPoint(attachmentPoint, objectToAssemble);
            }
            m_attach = false;
        }
        else if (obj.Code == PhotonEvents.OBJECT_DISASSEMBLED_EVENT)
        {
            object[] evData = (object[])obj.CustomData;
            GameObject attachmentPoint = FindCorrectAttachmentPoint((int)evData[0]);
            GameObject objectToDisassemble = FindCorrectPart((int)evData[1]);
            if (attachmentPoint == gameObject)
            {
                DisassembleFromPoint(attachmentPoint, objectToDisassemble);
            }

        }
    }

    private GameObject FindCorrectPart(int instanceId)
    {
        
        foreach (PartToBeAssembled part in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<PartToBeAssembled>())
        {
            if (part.gameObject.GetInstanceID() == instanceId)
                return part.gameObject;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private GameObject FindCorrectAttachmentPoint(int instanceId)
    {
        foreach (AttachementPoint attachmentPoint in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<AttachementPoint>())
        {
            if (attachmentPoint.gameObject.GetInstanceID() == instanceId)
                return attachmentPoint.gameObject;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void AssembleToPoint(GameObject attachmentPoint, GameObject assembledObject)
    {
        
        assembledObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
        assembledObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        assembledObject.transform.SetParent(gameObject.transform.parent);
        
        GameObject snappingPoint = DetermineSnappingPoint(snappingPoints, assembledObject);
        GameObject container = DetermineContainer(assembledObject);
        container.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(m_RotationOffset);
        if (snappingPoint != null)
            SnappingMethods.SnapTwoObjects(installationPoint, snappingPoint);
        else
            Debug.LogError("Non sono riuscito a trovare uno snapping point compatibile");

        assembledObject.GetComponent<PartToBeAssembled>().isAssembled = true;
        m_AssembledObject = assembledObject;
        
        gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
        gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material = m_DefaultMaterial;
    }

    private GameObject DetermineContainer(GameObject assembledObject)
    {
        foreach (GameObject container in containers)
        {
            if (assembledObject == container)
            {
                return container;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private GameObject DetermineSnappingPoint(List<GameObject> snappingPoints, GameObject assembledObject)
    {
        foreach(GameObject snapPoint in snappingPoints)
        {
            if(snapPoint == assembledObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject)
            {
                return snapPoint;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void DisassembleFromPoint(GameObject attachmentPoint, GameObject disassembledObject)
    {
        
        gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().enabled = true;
        disassembledObject.transform.SetParent(disassembledObject.GetComponent<PartToBeAssembled>().startingParent.transform, false);
    }


    private void TryChangeMaterials(GameObject grabbedObject, Material newMat)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Sono il metodo TryMakeYourselfMoreVisible dell'oggetto {gameObject}");

        if (m_CompatibleObjects.Contains(grabbedObject))
        {
            gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>().material = newMat;
        }
    }
        private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
        {
        
            if (m_attach)
            {   
                if (m_CompatibleObjects.Contains(other.gameObject) && other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() != null)
                {
                    
                    object[] eventData = new object[]{gameObject.GetInstanceID(), other.gameObject.GetInstanceID()};
                    PhotonNetwork.RaiseEvent(PhotonEvents.OBJECT_ASSEMBLED_EVENT, eventData, options, SendOptions.SendReliable);
                }
            }
        }
    public void NewObjectReleased(SelectExitEventArgs args)
    {
        TryChangeMaterials(args.interactableObject.transform.gameObject, m_DefaultMaterial);
        if(!m_attach)
            TryAttach();
    }

    public void NewObjectTakenBack(SelectEnterEventArgs args)
    {
        TryChangeMaterials(args.interactableObject.transform.gameObject, m_VisibleMaterial);
        TrySeparate(args.interactableObject.transform.gameObject);
    }
    public void TryAttach()
    {
        m_attach = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        {
            
            TrySeparate(m_AssembledObject);
        }
    }

    public void TrySeparate(GameObject objectToSeparate)
    {
        if(m_AssembledObject != null)
        {
            if (m_CompatibleObjects.Contains(objectToSeparate) && objectToSeparate == m_AssembledObject && objectToSeparate.GetComponent<PartToBeAssembled>().isAssembled)
            {
                objectToSeparate.GetComponent<PartToBeAssembled>().isAssembled = false;
                objectToSeparate.transform.SetParent(objectToSeparate.GetComponent<PartToBeAssembled>().startingParent.transform);
                object[] eventData = new object[] {gameObject.GetInstanceID(), objectToSeparate.GetInstanceID()};
                PhotonNetwork.RaiseEvent(PhotonEvents.OBJECT_DISASSEMBLED_EVENT, eventData, options, SendOptions.SendReliable);
                //hasBeenSeparated(gameObject, lastAssembledObject);
            }
        }
    }

}

this is the script that takes care of attaching two objects
